# Call model in model dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to call model comment in itself but cant't.
Error: Exception occured: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Comment'
Please help me.

```
 class Comment {
  Comment({
    this.id,
    this.author,
    this.isAuthor,
    this.isLiked,
    this.content,
    this.stats,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
    this.post,
    this.tagged,
    this.replies,
  });

  String id;
  Author author;
  bool isAuthor;
  bool isLiked;
  String content;
  Stats stats;
  DateTime createdAt;
  String updatedAt;
  String post;
  List<dynamic> tagged;
  List<Comment> replies;

  factory Comment.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Comment(
        id: json['_id'] as String,
        author: Author.fromJson(json['author'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
        isAuthor: json['isAuthor'] as bool,
        isLiked: json['isLiked'] as bool,
        content: json['content'] as String,
        stats: Stats.fromJson(json['stats'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
        createdAt: DateTime.parse(json['createdAt'] as String),
        updatedAt: json['updatedAt'] as String,
        post: json['post'] as String,
        tagged: List<dynamic>.from((json['tagged'] as List<dynamic>)
            .map<dynamic>((dynamic x) => x as Map<String, dynamic>)),
        replies: List<Comment>.from((json['replies'] as List<dynamic>)
            .map<dynamic>((dynamic x) => x as Map<String, dynamic>)),
      );
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your entire Comment model file code?

Comment: I updated full code create Comment.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your mapping of `replies`. You've declared the type of replies as

```
List<Comment> replies;
```

but in the fromJson method you are trying to assign a different type:

```
Map<String, dynamic>
```

To correct that you've to change your fromJson implementation:

```
class Comment {
    Comment({
        this.id,
        this.author,
        this.isAuthor,
        this.isLiked,
        this.content,
        this.stats,
        this.createdAt,
        this.updatedAt,
        this.post,
        this.tagged,
        this.replies,
    });

    int id;
    String author;
    bool isAuthor;
    bool isLiked;
    String content;
    String stats;
    DateTime createdAt;
    DateTime updatedAt;
    String post;
    List<dynamic> tagged;
    List<Comment> replies;

    factory Comment.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Comment(
        id:        json["id"],
        author:    json["author"],
        isAuthor:  json["isAuthor"],
        isLiked:   json["isLiked"],
        content:   json["content"],
        stats:     json["stats"],
        createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["createdAt"]),
        updatedAt: DateTime.parse(json["updatedAt"]),
        post:      json["post"],
        tagged:    List<dynamic>.from(json["tagged"].map((x) => x)),
        replies:   List<Comment>.from(json["replies"].map((x) => Comment.fromJson(x))),
    );
}
```